# Block configuration form values are not translated

Tags: 8

I have the following code in my custom block:

```
    public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $form['headline'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Block headline'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['headline']) ? $config['headline'] : NULL,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );


      return $form;
    }
```

and:

```
    public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $this->setConfigurationValue('headline', $form_state->getValue('headline'));
    }
```

The configuration is saved correctly, but only for English language.
The block translation doesn't show my variable (headline) in the translatable configuration.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.calibrate.be/news/translating-custom-block-plugin-configuration

It is a good instruction.

Comment: And please remember that you can't translate empty values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to provide a schema in `/config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml` of the type `block_settings`.

Example:

```
block.settings.example_configurable_text:
  type: block_settings
  label: 'Example configurable text block configuration'
  mapping:
    block_example_string:
      type: text
      label: 'Block contents'
```

From the example module
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/HEAD/modules/block_example/config/schema/block_example.schema.yml

Configurations mapped as `type: label` (single line of text) or `type: text` (multiple lines of text) are translatable.

Comment: Thanks! Can I add it anytime after enabling the module? Or do I need to add these values through a hook_update_N()?

Comment: the new schema yaml is discovered when you clear the cache

Comment: We dedicated a blog post about Config Translation (schema, default value, UI) in Drupal 8 with a full example: https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2018/05/01/drupal-8-how-to-translate-the-config-api

Comment: @GiDo great article! Can you advice: are theme_setting translatable? Cant make them work normal with translation :(