# Language specific settings for field formatters

Tags: 8

I've created a custom field formatter widget for numeric fields. The formatter has A LOT of settings to customize the visual output of that number, to whatever designers/marketing wants (adding a lot of HTML markup, with[out] leading/trailing zeros, zeros as dash, one or two fractions, rounding, prefixes/infixes/suffixes,... ).  Some of those settings are language-dependant though, so I'd like to enter different formatter settings in

/en/admin/structure/types/manage/MY_CONTENT_TYPE/display
/de/admin/structure/types/manage/MY_CONTENT_TYPE/display
/fr/admin/structure/types/manage/MY_CONTENT_TYPE/display

I've noticed that there is a `$langcode` parameter in
[FormatterInterface::viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FormatterInterface.php/function/FormatterInterface%3A%3AviewElements/8.5.x)

but I don't know how to make
[FormatterInterface.php FormatterInterface::settingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FormatterInterface.php/function/FormatterInterface%3A%3AsettingsForm/8.5.x)
language-aware.

Is it possible at all to have language-specific settings in a field formatter? If yes, how to I store and retrieve those settings in the correct language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Define a schema in your module
   *config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml*.

   Example from the date range module:

   [core/modules/datetime_range/config/schema/datetime_range.schema.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime_range%21config%21schema%21datetime_range.schema.yml/8.6.x)

   ```
   field.formatter.settings.daterange_default:
     type: field.formatter.settings.datetime_default
     label: 'Date range default display format settings'
     mapping:
       separator:
         type: label
         label: 'Separator'
         translation context: 'Date range separator'
   ```

   For more information see
   [Block configuration form values are not translated](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239432/block-configuration-form-values-are-not-translated)
2. You need an UI to translate, which is unfortunately not ready
   yet, see this issue:

   [Entity view/form mode formatter/widget settings have no translation
   UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2546212)

   Until then you can edit the translated yaml file of an exported
   config in *config/sync/language/[LanguageID]* or install the patch from the
   issue.

Comment: My module already has a working schema file, used for global settings though (same options, but not "per-node-bundle-scope"). I've added a top level key `field.formatter.settings.MY_MODULE` of `type: mapping` with all my translatable labels and did a config export. But in which config files are the per-nodebundle-specific formatter settings supposed to be stored? I did not find any additional keys except my already existing (global) module config.

Comment: The translated yaml files in `language/[LanguageID]` are named identically as the untranslated ones in the main sync folder. The main difference is that they only contain the translatable values. But why not fork your local site and try out the patch. You don't need the patch later in production when you deploy the config.

Comment: OK, got it by trial & error. Even after creating the schema, no config for the field formatter was exported in the 2nd lang. I manually copied `core.entity_view_display.node.NODE_TYPE.VIEW_MODE.yml` to `config/lang/ISO2CODE`, deleted all keys except those marked for translation and reimported the config. Then it worked.