# Where can we translate Format settings label?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am just wondering that where we can translate the **Format setting** labels which is configured in Manage display of content type. I checked in configuration translation, user interface translation but i didn't find the label which i am searching for.Can anyone help me in this regard. please find below screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269842/language-specific-settings-for-field-formatters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Language specific settings for field formatters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269842/language-specific-settings-for-field-formatters) - the UI patch mentioned there is not really beautiful, but still works (Drupal v8.7)