# Why isn't config for Views plugin module translatable?

Tags: views, 9, configuration

I am trying to write up a patch for this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/readmore. There is a patch for it: https://www.drupal.org/project/readmore/issues/3055200 which adds configurable text for the "read more" and "read less" links provided by this field formatter. But the configuration for these new settings are not translatable.

I noticed that the readmore.schema.yml did not include entries for these new fields (although the new configuration options do work). I added this:

```
readmore_text:
  type: string
  label: 'Read more link text'
readless_text:
  type: string
  label: 'Read less link text'
```

To the .schema file but it doesn't help.

What is missing to trigger translation of this view to show these new configuration options?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for translatable strings you need `type: label`. Then the Views entity field schema

*views.field.schema.yml:*

```
views.field.field:
  type: views_field
  label: 'Views entity field handler'
  mapping:
    click_sort_column:
      type: string
      label: 'Column used for click sorting'
    type:
      type: string
      label: 'Formatter'
    settings:
      label: 'Settings'
      type: field.formatter.settings.[%parent.type]
```

expects a field formatter schema with this structure:

```
field.formatter.settings.daterange_default:
  type: field.formatter.settings.datetime_default
  label: 'Date range default display format settings'
  mapping:
    separator:
      type: label
      label: 'Separator'
      translation context: 'Date range separator'
```

This example is extending a base class and so it is also extending the schema. Otherwise you can replace the type reference to the parent formatter with `type: mapping`. See also [Language specific settings for field formatters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269842/language-specific-settings-for-field-formatters)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Took a while to try to see what all of that was.. but turns out my only issue was I had type: string when it needed to be type: label. :)