# How to make view display plugin translatable?

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom view display plugin which extends from the block plugin.
When I add a display on the view, the fields or anything in the display is not translatable (see image below)
[image]

How can I make the fields in the view display plugin translatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a schema (where `products_block` is the plugin ID):

*/config/schema/mymodule.views.schema.yml*

```
views.display.products_block:
  type: views.display.block
  label: 'Products block display options'
  mapping:
    ...
```

This extends `views.display.block` of /core/modules/views/config/schema/views.display.schema.yml, which extends  `views_display` of /core/modules/views/config/schema/views.data_types.schema.yml

More info [Block configuration form values are not translated](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239432/block-configuration-form-values-are-not-translated)?

Comment: Thanks @4k4 , that worked! One small adjustment I made: the file should be named mymodule.views.schema.yml